# What is @Entity in Spring JPA?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, entity

Specifically, I am referring to javax.persistence.Entity.

Based on the documentation it shows when I hover the mouse over, in VS Code it states that:

> Specifies that the class is an entity. This annotation is applied to
> the entity class.

What does it mean for Spring JPA that a class is an Entity?

Comment: Why the dislike?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

a class of type Entity indicates a class that, at an abstract level, is correlated with a table in the database.
Each object instantiated by this class indicates a tuple of the table itself, containing the information of the latter.
I recommend that you find out about what [object relational mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) is.
I also recommend [this page](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/4.2.7.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html) that talks about (Spring docs) of ORM on Spring

Comment: Another thing that can help understand ORM is this video on youtube. https://youtu.be/LooPUh5_QKI 

But overall, an Entity is an abstraction of a database object, which lets you focus on the structure of your objects and not having to build SQL queries.

Answer (score 3):

I did some searching around to find an answer. I decided to post it anyway,
I looked up
[docs.oracle.com](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbqa.html#:%7E:text=An%20entity%20is%20a%20lightweight,entities%20can%20use%20helper%20classes.) before posting my question.

> An entity is a lightweight persistence domain object. Typically, an
> entity represents a table in a relational database, and each entity
> instance corresponds to a row in that table. The primary programming
> artifact of an entity is the entity class, although entities can use
> helper classes.

An entity class must follow these requirements.

> - The class must be annotated with the javax.persistence.Entity    annotation.

> - The class must have a public or protected, no-argument constructor.      The class may have other constructors.

> - The class must not be declared final. No methods or persistent       instance variables must be declared final.

> - If an entity instance is passed by value as a detached object, such      as through a session bean’s remote business interface, the class must
>   implement the Serializable interface.

> - Entities may extend both entity and non-entity classes, and       non-entity classes may extend entity classes.

> - Persistent instance variables must be declared private, protected, or    package-private and can be accessed directly only by the entity
>   class’s methods. Clients must access the entity’s state through accessor or business methods.

Another interesting resource is this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r3qpqHMQtfI)

TL;DR: @Entity annotation defines that a class can be mapped to a table.

Comment: read Hibernate documentation or a book on Hibernate. It is an important topic that is worth investing some time in to avoid hours of googling later. And did you just say VS Code? :/

Comment: I have intellij but I'm just used to vs code lol...

Comment: Yeah I thought so:)

Comment: I will definitely be reading more technical books in the future. But, I think for now, stackoverflow and the alike suit my needs just fine. But thank you for your comment :) It sure is one cool way to think about it; reading a book might take some time, but it will save so much more in the future.