# Not able to create table in database getting error that table is not found

Tags: spring-boot, mysql-workbench

I am getting 500 internal server error postman while post the data not able to create table using @entity in database.
could not extract ResultSet, Table 'microservices1.user' doesn't exist, o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1146, SQLState: 42S02

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHBem.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjlB2.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exxGR.png)

Answer (score 0):

Well the error is pretty clear your database doest not have a table named user the schema microservices1.

You need to create first the table user in the database, manually or using migrations lib

Comment: But the table should be create automatically because i uses @entity then why i need to create the table manually

Comment: Entity means this class is linked to table in a database and thus making possible the connection  between an object in your application and  its representation in the database.

Comment: It will not create the table for you, see 
https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-entities 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63414381/what-is-entity-in-spring-jpa